# Default import three.js in javascript modules gives "_three2.default is undefined"

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, module, three.js

I see examples of using three.js like this:

```
import THREE from 'three';

var a = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
var b = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(...);
```

When I try to do this, I get `_three2.default is undefined` error.
Meaning that `three` module does not export default.
Checking `three.module.js` file I see that indeed it does not export default, but instead every component by name.

I use webpack to bundle and load modules.

How to use `import THREE from 'three';`?

Comment: Just `import * as THREE from …` if you want to refer to everything with a namespace prefix?

Comment: Cool. This works. In some examples I see just "import THREE from 'three';". But this should satisfy me :).